# What are some popular ember.js open-source projects?

Tags: open-source, ember.js, project

I'm looking for more ember.js projects to learn from. If you know any, please provide in the format of: *[running site](http://todomvc.com/architecture-examples/emberjs/) and [source code](https://github.com/tastejs/todomvc/tree/gh-pages/architecture-examples/emberjs)*

Note that both components should be provided, because there are too many example source code tutorials that I can't get to run. So they don't even have to be examples, tutorials, or have explanations, simply a running website with its source code would be good enough to learn from.

I am especially interested in stand-alone ember.js projects, without interactions with Ruby and others. Pure Ember.js running example websites with code.

---

Answers Compiled: Stand-alone ember.js open source projects:

- [TodoMVC](http://todomvc.com/architecture-examples/emberjs/) and [source](https://github.com/tastejs/todomvc/tree/gh-pages/architecture-examples/emberjs)
- [Emberpress game](http://emberpress.eviltrout.com/) and [Github source](https://github.com/eviltrout/emberpress), [annotated source](http://emberpress.eviltrout.com/docs/emberpress.html)
- [Bloggr-client](http://jsbin.com/ajewot/3/edit) and [Github source](https://github.com/tildeio/bloggr-client)

Comment: One of the biggest open source project made with ember.js is discourse.org

Comment: I'd suggest the best way to learn is start building something of your own, I know it will consume lot of time compared to looking one of the readymade projects and learning, but it's worth it !

Answer (score 5):

Check out:
http://emberwatch.com/#examples

Not only do they have great examples there but also a collection of tutorials and screencasts

Answer (score 4):

Checkout out this:

https://github.com/discourse/discourse

And the running fully functional website :

http://www.discourse.org/